# create object intelligently with java

Tags: java, android, class, initialization

I am programming with android application, but the method I create view is so tedious, anyone have good idea with them?

```
    MapView mMapView1 = new MapView(getActivity(),1);
    initialMapView(mMapView1);

    MapView mMapView2 = new MapView(getActivity(),2);
    initialMapView(mMapView2);

    MapView mMapView3 = new MapView(getActivity(),3);
    initialMapView(mMapView3);

    MapView mMapView4 = new MapView(getActivity(),4);
    initialMapView(mMapView4);

    MapView mMapView5 = new MapView(getActivity(),5);
    initialMapView(mMapView5);

    MapView mMapView6 = new MapView(getActivity(),6);
    initialMapView(mMapView6);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks very much like you could do with an array or a list:

```
List<MapView> mapViews = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    MapView mapView = new MapView(getActivity(), i);
    initialMapView(mapView);
    mapViews.add(mapView);
}
```

(You can now use `mapViews.get(...)` to get at each element later.)

EDIT: Note that both arrays and `List<E>` are 0-based - so in the example above, you'd use `mapViews.get(0)` to get the `MapView` initialized with a second argument of `1`.

Comment: @Haven: Well I've used an `List<MapView>` there - you could use a `MapView[]` instead, and then get `MapView[1]`, although you'd be best off using 0-based indexing (as both `List<E>` and arrays do).

Comment: Thanks a lot, one more question, if I want to make a 2-d ArrayList, is it MapView[][] and ArrayList<MapView<MapView>>? I guess first one is more friendly to use

Comment: @Haven: It would be `List<List<MapView>>`, but you'd need to initialize sub-lists etc - it does get to be a bit of a pain. If the lengths are fixed, an array may well be simpler.

Comment: Thanks, I will now make them into practise.

Comment: There's a hidden danger here.  The indexes to the `get` method start at zero.  So if you write `mapViews.get(1)`, you're actually going to get the object that you were earlier calling `mMapView2` - that is, the one that was created as `new MapView(getActivity(), 2 )`.